# Matplotlib font (not size) of annotation text

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

After looking on the matplotlib website I found the example code for a pie chart that has the perfect properties in terms of customization and functionally. However, I would like to change the font (not size). I have been unable to find out how to do this for the annotations which you can see here...

[image]

It would be better if I could specify by name the font (like 'Helvetica' or 'Times_New_Roman') rather than the other ways that you can change font in matplotlib.

Here is the code for the above image...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

recipe = ["225 g flour",
          "90 g sugar",
          "1 egg",
          "60 g butter",
          "100 ml milk",
          "1/2 package of yeast"]

data = [225, 90, 50, 60, 100, 5]

wedges, texts = ax.pie(data, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5), startangle=-40)

bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
kw = dict(xycoords='data', textcoords='data', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"),
          bbox=bbox_props, zorder=0, va="center")

for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
    ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1)/2. + p.theta1
    y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
    x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
    horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
    connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang)
    kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
    ax.annotate(recipe[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(1.35*np.sign(x), 1.4*y),
                 horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw)

ax.set_title("Matplotlib bakery: A donut")

plt.show()
```

Note, I am also really confused as to where I would place the lines of code specific to the text of the labels in the actual program.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the font, you can add the parameter family in the annotate function

```
ax.annotate(recipe[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(1.35*np.sign(x), 1.4*y),
             horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw, family='fantasy')
```

There are more font styles available. You can read more about it on the Matplotlib documentation.
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html